# DS212j NAS cant install DSM 5.0-4493

Tags: nas, synology

So I got a second hand ds212j it has 1 blank hdd in it currently in the disk 2 spot. Synology Assistant sees the device, but when I go to install DSM 4493 Synology Assistant tells me I need version 4493 or higher, but that is the only one i see on the site. I read to try to do the ip of the device and port 5000 but that didn't work and i think that's because its a brand new hdd with no DSM. I have also tried to find older versions of Synology Assistant, but could not find one.

Synology Assistant is version 5.0-4448

How to get DSM installed on this new machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can't login to the device because the DSM isn't installed yet.

The .pat file downloaded needs to not have any extra characters in it (I tried to download the global file first, Asia was quicker but saved with (1) in the filename).

File named DSM_DS212j_4493.pat will work to install the DSM.

Hope this helps.